# Is it reliable to use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode toString() instead of ObjectMapper writeValueAsString(Object value) method

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I need to serialize the `JsonNode` object to *String*. I was using
`ObjectMapper's writeValueAsString(Object value)` but I see that the `JsonNode toString()` produces the same result. Also looking at the `toString()` implementations of it's sub-classes such as `TextNode`, `ArrayNode` etc. it looks they are doing it correctly.

The *JsonNode* object which I want to serialize is never `null`, so there is no risk of NPE being thrown when calling *toString()*.

I am using `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar` and referring to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` classes.

**My question:** Is `JsonNode's toString()` method as reliable as `ObjectMapper's writeValueAsString(Object value)` method for serializing `JsonNode` object to `String`?
What are the important differences between the two.

Comment: Take a look on [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString--): Method that will produce (as of Jackson 2.10) valid `JSON` using default settings of databind, as `String`. If you want other kinds of `JSON` output (or output formatted using one of other `Jackson`-supported data formats) make sure to use `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter` to serialize an instance, for example: `String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);`

Comment: It changed between `2.9` and `2.10`. Does that mean I should not use `toString()` if I am on `2.9.9`?
***2.9 says:*** `Method that will produce developer-readable representation of the node; which may or may not be as valid JSON. If you want valid JSON output (or output formatted using one of other Jackson supported data formats) make sure to use ObjectMapper or ObjectWriter to serialize an instance`

***2.10 says:*** Method that will produce (as of Jackson 2.10) valid JSON using default settings of databind, as String. If you want other kinds of JSON output make sure to use ObjectMapper

Comment: @MichałZiober & @Sotirios Delimanolis Is it bad if I use `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object value)` when my `value` object can either be a `String`  or an object containing `JsonNode`. I want to avoid that type check and use same method call for both.

Comment: If version `2.9` does not guarantee you can use it safely, try to avoid it and use `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter` instead. Why would you like to serialise a `String`? What the result do you expect? `ObjectMapper` probably will wrap it in `"{value}"`, so if ti works for you, you can use it.